# Flutter Google Charts changing fontWeight of TextStyleSpec

Tags: flutter, charts

I'm using the google charts library for my flutter app and I'm trying to customize the styling of my lables.

But how can I change the fontweight of a `TextStyleSpec`? the parameter `fontWeight` asks for a `String`, I tried providing `Bold`, `bold`, `500`, `w500` but none work.

Answer (score 8):

Quickly [searching](https://github.com/google/charts/search?q=fontweight&unscoped_q=fontweight) through the source code of the [charts_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/charts_flutter) library on Github shows that the `fontWeight` property of the `TextStyleSpec` is never used. I would assume the library does not truly support setting the font weight.

Comment: Oh okay I searched in the code too but couldn't find anything, that might explain it. Thank you!

Comment: There is an issue for that https://github.com/google/charts/issues/351

Answer (score -3):

Are you using the correct syntax?
The syntax for the fontweight parameter uses the FontWeight class to modify the text, i.e., the value of fontweight can be supplied using the FontWeight consts. 
For example,
fontweight: FontWeight.bold
fontweight: FontWeight.w800

Comment: I'm talking about the `TextStyleSpec` Object from the Google Charts library, not the normal TextStyle Object, this one somehow wants a String for the fontweight...